# Flask render_template() not working in Azure Web App

Tags: python, html, azure, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to debug my Flask app. I have it deployed on Azure Web App via Git-Hub deployment.
The code works perfectly fine on localhost, renders the table and everything, however, when deployed to Azure, everything works fine EXCEPT for render_template() with a table.

Here's what I mean:

```
# This is my view route in quess_blueprint.py
@quess_blueprint.route('/view_all_quests')
def view_all_quests():
    limit = 10
    quests_collection = mongo.db.quests
    offset = int(request.args['offset'])
    quests_table = list(quests_collection .find({}).sort('_id', mongo.ASCENDING).limit(limit)))
    print(quests_table) # I see the result in the Console so i know it's getting the data
    next_url = BASE_ROUTE+'productivity_suite/'+route_name+'?offset=' + str(offset + limit)
    prev_url = BASE_ROUTE+'productivity_suite/'+route_name+'?offset=' + str(offset - limit)
    return render_template('quests/quests_table.html', quests_table=quests_table, next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url)
```

```
# This is my html for quests_table.html
.
.
.
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for quest in quests %}
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Quest Name">{{quest.quest_name}}</td>
          <td data-label="Quest Priority">{{quest.quest_priority}}</td>
          <td data-label="Due Date">{{quest.due_date}}</td>
          <td data-label="Completed Date">{{quest.completed_date}}</td>
          <td data-label="Quest Elder">{{quest.quest_elder}}</td>
          <td data-label="Primary Assigned">{{quest.primary_user}}</td>
          <td data-label="Secondary Assigned">{{quest.secondary_user}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I run this locally, I can see the result of the `print(quests_table)` and the code renders the quests table.

However, when I deploy to Azure, and look at the Log Stream, I still can see the result of the `print(quests_table)` and the code renders the html template, with the table head, buttons, etc, but without the table body from the For Loop.

I'm not sure why Azure is not reading the For Loop correctly.

I've tried so many things like changing the template, making the list into a dataframe and then to_html and still doesn't work. Literally everything else works.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

1. Make sure you have got http response.

   Press F12, check the http request.
2. If get response, check if the returned result is what you want.
3. If get null or empty result, check the sql connectionstrings.
4. If you try the above methods and there is no problem, check your local python version, flask version, and try to create the same azure webapp as the local version. You can also try to create a containner app. If everything is normal without modifying the code, there may be a bug in the specific version of the azure webapp pyhton platform.
5. And suggest you check application logs on portal, if no error, you maybe need [contact MSFT by raising a support ticket on portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).